# SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler await*() in I/O thread causes a dead lock

Tags: multithreading, netty

In my Netty `SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler` when I receive a message I need to start up a connection to another Netty Server and forward the message on. However, when starting up this second connection I use:

```
ChannelFuture channelFuture = clientBootstrap.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
hannelFuture.awaitUninterruptibly();
```

Which results in the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: await*() in I/O thread causes a dead lock or sudden performance drop. Use addListener() instead or call await*() from a different thread.
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.checkDeadLock(DefaultChannelFuture.java:314)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.awaitUninterruptibly(DefaultChannelFuture.java:226)
    at com.my.NettyClient.start(NettyClient.java:204)
  ....
  at com.my.MyChannelUpstreamHandler.messageReceived(MyChannelUpstreamHandler.java:52)
```

Whats the best way to start this second connection? Should I do the following?:

```
    @Override
    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) throws Exception {

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        executorService.submit(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Connect to another Netty Server...

                // Forward on message...
            }
        });

        executorService.shutdown();
...
```

Is this wasteful to start a new thread on each message recieved?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the proxy example to see how you can do it without blocking:

http://netty.io/docs/stable/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/proxy/HexDumpProxyInboundHandler.html

Comment: That links seems to have changed. Here is an [updated one](http://static.netty.io/3.6/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/proxy/HexDumpProxyInboundHandler.html)